# String Parsing in C with an argument given in main

Tags: c, linux, string, char

I am passing an argument in main and want to include that argument in one of the lines of code. I was having a tough time incorporating it into the code.
This is the code:

```
   int main(char *argv[])
   {
       FILE *in;
       char buff[512];
       // char temp [512];

       // /nfs/engfs/haquresh/Desktop -> should be argument given in main
       // " find argv[] -type f | wc -l", "r" this is want i want stored in a char temp
       if (!(in = popen("find /nfs/engfs/haquresh/Desktop -type f | wc -l", "r")))
       {

        return 1;
       }
```

It should be basic char manipulative in C, I was just having a hard time with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have declared `main()` incorrectly - `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. The first argument tells how many string arguments are passed to it. The first string pointed to by the second argument is usually the executable's filename.

Comment: Hi hasan. I see you're new to Stack Overflow. Once you've received a good answer, you should mark the answer you like as the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, a program that invokes arbitrary parameters as code may be a serious security problem.

```
/* popen1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fin;
    int i;
    char cmd[ 4096 ];

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Must specify arguments\n");
        return -1;
        }
    sprintf(cmd, "find %s |wc -l", argv[1]);

    fin = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!fin) {
        perror("popen");
        return -1;
        }
    while(!feof(fin)) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin) != NULL)
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    pclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile as `cc -opopen1 popen1.c`.

Run thusly:  `./popen1 /nfs/engfs/haquresh/Desktop`

Comment: How does this code give fopen this argument "find /nfs/engfs/haquresh/Desktop -type f | wc -l", "r" ?

Comment: i only want this to be the argument /nfs/engfs/haquresh/Desktop.

Comment: @hasanqureshi whatever you type as arguments.

Comment: @user590028: Please make that `len = snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "find %s |wc -l", argv[1]); if (len < 1 || (size_t)len >= sizeof cmd) { printf("Path %s is too long.\n", argv[1]); return EXIT_FAILURE; }`, with `int len;`, so that there is no risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: Then, backup your entire `$HOME` and after that, run `./popen1 "$HOME; rm -rf $HOME"` while reading the wikipage on [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid running any `find` process from your C program, since you just can (and probably should) use the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) function to search your tree.

Doing the search internally with `nftw` would avoid a process. BTW, the functionality of `| wc -l` is also very simple to program in C.

If you insist on running a pipe, you don't need to code a C program; you could just make a shell script like

```
#!/bin/sh
find $* -type f | wc -l
```

This is shorter (but not slower) than your C program ; be scared of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) when coding in C a dynamicly built command string (for  `system` or `popen`)

Regarding string manipulation in C, learn about [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (but avoid using `sprintf`) or, on Linux with glibc, [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)